# How to automatically select OpenOffice Calc cells based on a formula?

Tags: openoffice.org, openoffice-calc

I can select cells with a mouse to copy them to clipboard.
Is there a way to have them selected based on a formula?

Answer (score 0):

Go to *Edit -> Find and Replace*. Under *Other options*, *Search in `Formulas`* is the default setting.

Enter what you want to search for in the *Find* box, then press *Find All*. After the dialog is closed, the cells will still be selected.